# Use AJAX to update Django Model

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-models

I am trying to understand how to *update* a Django model using AJAX without loading a new page or explicitly having the user press a save button. I have found  many tutorials that deal with getting results from Django models using AJAX but I haven't found any that deal with updating models using AJAX.

Here is what I have so far

I have the following Django model:

```py
#models.py 

class Upload(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    language = models.ForeignKey('about.channel', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='Other')
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    file = models.FileField()
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I am accepting those uploads through a form, all is well. I am then displaying those on a page through the following view:

```py
#views.py

def submissions(request):
    context = {
        'uploads': Upload.objects.all().order_by('-completed', '-date')
    }

    return render(request, 'content/submissions.html', context)
```

The template for this page:

```html
#submissions.html

            <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3">
                {% for upload in uploads %}
                <div class="col mb-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title"> {{ upload.title }} </h5>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle"> {{upload.language}} </h6>
                            <a href="{{ upload.file.url }}" class="channel-link card-link" download> Download </a>
                            {% if upload.completed %}
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" data-id="{{ upload.id }}" checked>
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ upload.id }}"> Completed </label>
                                </div>
                            {% else %}
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" data-id="{{ upload.id }}">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ upload.id }}"> Completed </label>
                                </div>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
```

Here is a portion of the page:
[image: Page Description]

The checkboxes work, and returns the appropriate checked vs unchecked on the `completed` model field.

I am trying to understand how to connect this to AJAX in order to be able to update the `completed` model field from just clicking the checkbox located on each card on the page without  having to load a new page/model or press a save button. I have tried the following view for updating the model but no luck:

```py
#views.py

def completed(request, *args, **kwargs):
    upload = Upload.objects.get(id=id)
    upload.completed = not upload.complete
    upload.save()

    return JsonResponse({'status': 200})
```

And the jQuery/AJAX:

```js
$('.form-check').on('click', '.form-check-input', function() {
    var dataID = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'content/completed/',
        data: {
            id: dataID
        },
        success: function () {
            console.log('Success')
        }
    })
});
```

Alas, I get nothing. I'm sure I have things wrong in both my view I'm using to update and the AJAX call, but I'm at a loss for what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your form is firing off your AJAX call successfully with the correct data. Maybe you aren't accessing your AJAX post parameter correctly

Your api:

```
def completed(request)
    id = request.POST.get('id')   # Add this line

    upload = Upload.objects.get(id=id)
    upload.completed = not upload.complete
    upload.save()
    
    return JsonResponse({'status': 200})
```

If this doesn't solve it, let me know what messages you are getting from the backend, and what sort of data you sent in your Ajax call. If you use FireFox, press ctrl+shift+I and click on Network tab to see what data you sent from your Ajax call.

**In regard to your comment about CSRF, try putting this code (csrfSafeMethod() and $.ajaxSetup()) before you call your $.ajax()**

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
};

...

$('.form-check').on('click', '.form-check-input', function() {
    var dataID = $(this).data('id');
    
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", Cookies.get('csrftoken'));
            }
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "content/completed/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            id: dataID
        },
        success: function () {
            console.log('Success')
        }
    })
});
```

This was how I handled CSRF for my APIs without putting them into @csrf_exempt, maybe it will work for you too

Comment: That was it! Now one other question. I just moved the view to @csrf_exempt but I'd rather have CSRF for protection. What's the best way to handle this when I don't have a form on the page?

Comment: I made an update to the answer regarding your comment, the answer was too long to put into comments :)